# Lightning Component error question

Tags: component, lighting-web-component

I am trying to make a component to use lightning:datatable to display Contacts in an Account.

I am getting this error when I attempt to open an Account in my page :

```
A Component Error has occured! Error: Action failed: c:contactList$controller$myAction [v is not defined] 
Component: c:contactList . Caused by: Action failed: c:contactList$controller$myAction [v is not defined]
```

That's not a very helpful error.

This is my code...

**Apex Controller 'ContactController':**

```
public class ContactController {

    @AuraEnabled
    public static List<Contact> getContacts(Id recordId) {
        return [SELECT Id, FirstName, LastName, Email, Phone
               FROM Contact WHERE AccountId =: recordId];
    }
}
```

**My component 'contactList':**

```
    <aura:component controller="ContactController"
                implements="flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId" 
                access="global" >
    <aura:attribute name="recordId" type="Id"/>
    <aura:attribute name="Account" type="Account"/>
    <aura:attribute name="Contacts" type="Contact"/>
    <aura:attribute name="Columns" type="List"/>
    
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action ="{!c.myAction}"/>
    
     <force:recordData aura:id="accountRecord"
                       recordId="{!v.recordId}"
                       targetFields="{!v.Account}"
                       layoutType="FULL"
                       />
    <lightning:card iconName="standard:contact"
                    title="{!'Contact List for ' + v.Account.Name}">
    <lightning:datatable data="{v.Contacts}" columns="{v.Columns}"
                         keyField="Id" hideCheckboxColumn="false"/>
</lightning:card>
                                                 
</aura:component>
```

**My js controller 'contactListController' : **

```
({
    myAction : function(component, event, helper) {
        component.set("v.Columns",[
            {label:"First Name", fieldName:"FirstName",type:"text"},
            {label:"Last Name", fieldName:"LastName",type:"text"},
            {label:"Phone", fieldName:"Phone",type:"phone"},
                        
        ]);
        
        var action = component.get("c.getContacts");
            action.setParams({
                recordId: component.get(v.recordId)
            });
            action.setCallback(this, function(data){
                component.set("v.Contacts", data.getReturnValue());
            
            });
            $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }
})
```

I don't understand what I am not defining. It must be a stupid overlook on my part. I thought it might help to have another set of eyes look at it. If you can tell me anything I would be very grateful. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SecureComponent.get` needs a string value:

```
component.get(v.recordId)
```

Should be:

```
component.get('v.recordId')
```

It's a pretty easy mistake to make, and relatively hard to spot if you're not paying attention.

Comment: Thank you so much !

Comment: I was having a problem displaying the actual datatable - but then I realized I was also missing my ! in my names. Thanks again for your help @sfdcfox !